# Why AJAX send two requests where the second is null

Tags: jquery, ajax, request

I have a problem with my code here, why my ajax function returns two responses. The first one is exactly what I'm expecting but the second one is equal to 0.

Here is the code :

```
$('td p #btn').each(function (index) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var qte = $(this).parent().prev().find('input').val();
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'myfunction',
                qteP: qte,
                index: index
            },
            success: function ($result) {

                $(this).parent().parent().prev().html($result);

            }
        })
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).prev().show();
        $(this).parent().prev().text(qte);
    });
});
```

Comment: you shouldn't use each loop here. BTW, IDs must be unique on context page

Comment: Since an ID must be unique, you only need `$('#btn')` as that will be the fastest, and there is only one in that set, so you don't need to add the event manager that way inside the `.each()`

Comment: Define "returns two responses."  What is the actual behavior you're seeing?  That click handler doesn't "return" anything.  Are you getting unexpected data in the `$result` on the `success` handler?  Are you invoking the click handler more than once?  (Which might be happening.  If you have multiple elements with the same `id` then the behavior is undefined and could vary by browser.)

Comment: @David He says the ajax call returns two responses, not the click event handler.

Comment: @KevinB I'm 99% sure the event is happening twice.  I was just answering David's comment about the click handler not returning anything, since that's not what he said :)

Comment: The ajax request is only returning one response (unless it's a cors request i guess.) Most likely what is happening is you're actually sending two requests, either due to two handlers being bound to the event, or the event being triggered twice. Duplicate ID's are bad, but i don't think that's causing you a problem in this case.